# how to disable Content security policy using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, google-chrome

In my existing project Content security policy is enabled for security reason but i want to disabled it for some JavaScript files.Is it possible to do it ?

I want to call some APIs from my JavaScript files to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test it, why don't you just use a CSP and CORS plugin for your browser?
This allows you turn off CSP and CORS security for your SPA.

CSP:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden?hl=en

CORS;
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

But there is a reason to why there are these securities when its client-application. So I would suggest you not to try to disable anything Its for your own secruity

Comment: thanks for replying Zot3x ,i know this but i'm looking for disabling security policy using javascript code.

Comment: The initial question was disabling via JS, not an extension. So if an extension did it, it is then possible to code it in JS. But how ??